# Displaying Content w/ Button Clicks

Tags: java, android

I have ten buttons, 0-9 and when one is pressed I want to display its value into a TextView. So the initial display looks like this:

0.00

If I press the 2 button then it should be displayed to the TextView like this:

0.02

Now if I pressed 5 then the new value should be:

0.25

and so on. I've never done anything like this so I'm not exactly sure where to begin. So my question is, whats the best way to implement something like this?

**EDIT:** I know how to display content when a button is pressed, however, I'm not sure how to transition the each number when a new button is pressed into its new position.

Comment: What's the text you are showing on each button ?

Comment: Its a similar display as a basic calculator.

Comment: So the maximum number in your case would be 9.99, right ?

Comment: I want it to display 9,999.99 if I pressed nine, nine times with the comma automatically inserted, but with an initial value of zero.

Comment: Not sure I understand, bare with me please. So you have 10 buttons 0 - 9 when you click button one (for instance) you want the display to be 0.1 or do you want it to be 1? Also did you do this using an array of JButtons or did you set them up one at a time? (the more information we get the better we can help you)

Comment: I setup each button one at a time. Similar to your first statement @Afflicted. Its input for dollar amounts, so If I wanted to display 1 cent to the TextView I would only have to press one, one time. On the other hand, if I wanted to display 1 dollar then I would press one then zero, zero.

Comment: Have you tried just setting the text to "0", "1", etc? From there it's simple enough to convert to a double and preform w/e math you need.

Comment: Ok, yeah, I could try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store an int with the value you are displaying and as you input the number multiply that value by 10 and add the new number on.

Something like:

```
public void updateValue(int buttonPressed){
    currentValue = (currentValue*10) + buttonPressed;
}
```

then where you're updating the TextView make sure you format the string in a suitable way:

```
    public String formatNum(){
    String valueAsString = Integer.toString(currentValue); 
    while(valueAsString.length()<3){
        valueAsString = '0' + valueAsString; 
    }
    char[] stringBuilding = new char[valueAsString.length()+(((valueAsString.length())-2)/3)+1];
    int valueAsStringPtr = valueAsString.length()-1; 
    int stringBuildingPtr = stringBuilding.length-1;
    while(stringBuildingPtr>=0){
        if(stringBuildingPtr==stringBuilding.length-3){
            stringBuilding[stringBuildingPtr--] = '.'; 
        } else if((stringBuilding.length-stringBuildingPtr-3)%4==0){
            stringBuilding[stringBuildingPtr--] = ','; 
        } else { 
            stringBuilding[stringBuildingPtr--] = valueAsString.charAt(valueAsStringPtr--);
        }
    }
    String returnVal = String.copyValueOf(stringBuilding);  
    return returnVal; 
}
```

All this assumes you have an integer field currentValue.

Also try to do this on a worker thread ideally to avoid lagging out UI, it shouldn't really take too long, but still a good idea.

Note: for anyone wondering why I elected to use ints instead of float/double is because then we will introduce error displaying a binary representation as a decimal.